# scala jdbc template and rowmapper

Tags: spring, scala, jdbc

I am new to Scala and I am looking at a bit of Scala code which involves a Spring JDBC template and a RowMapper:

It is something like this:

```
val db = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(QUERY, new RowMapper[SomeObject]() {
  def mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) {
     var s = new SomeObject()
     s.setParam1 = rs.getDouble("columnName")
     return s
  }
  })
   db
```

I am writing this from memory so I have just used generic names.

I was wondering  why db is written at the end. I can't think of what purpose it serves.

Also, If I had several JDBC templates and an object like `s` in the example where I wanted to populate it's data with output from the several JDBC templates. Is it possible to do this in one function? Is it possible to have a mapRow function which doesn't return anything so that I could maybe have an array of templates and loop through them?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `db` at the end means `return db` where return statement is skipped. This is a standard convention in Scala. Seems like your code is a body of the function which suppose to return `db`. The first statement simply assigns the result of the query to a `db`

RowMapper interface can be replaced with [implicit conversion](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/ruby/implicit-conversions-more-powerful-than-dynamic-typing) to a function of the following type `(ResultSet, Int) => SomeObject`, which means that it takes two parameters (ResultSet and Int) and returns the result of type SomeObject